# Displaying TIF image using byte array to writeable bitmap(C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a byte array of a tiff image. I want to form 3 images from it,that i'll do later but the problem is i'm not able to display the original image as it is.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="ReferenceImage"/>
```

xaml.cs code:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ImagePath = @"G:\TiffImage\Test.TIF"
            DisplayAllImages();
        }

        private void DisplayAllImages()
        {

            byte[] imageSize = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);

            ReferenceImage.Source = DisplayAllImages(imageSize, 64, 64);
     }

private WriteableBitmap DisplayAllImages(byte[] imageData,int height,int width)
        {
            if (imageData != null)
            {

                PixelFormat format = PixelFormats.Gray8;
                WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(height, width, 96, 96, format, null);
                wbm.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, height, width), imageData, 1*width, 0);
                return wbm;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

My main aim is to display image using byte array like this way only, so that i can extract byte array to form other image as per requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image file contains encoded bitmap data. In order to access the raw pixels you would first have to decode the bitmap:

```
BitmapSource bitmap;

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
        fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

Now you would get the raw pixels by calling the `CopyPixels` method of the BitmapSource:

```
var width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
var height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
var stride = (width * bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
var imageData = new byte[height * stride];

bitmap.CopyPixels(imageData, stride, 0);
```

Comment: i want to form 4 images from a byte array, let say i've a byte array of size [64*64*4] so from the each 4 bytes(32 bit) like  10,10,11,1 bits images, size of one image would have 64*64 bytes. How can i do this?

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. Do you want to separate the ARGB channels?

Comment: Ok, Let say i have a byte array of an image of size 16384(64*64*4)bytes. Now i've to form four images from it. so i've to divide each 32 bits into four part like first image is of 10 bits, second image is of 10 bits, third image is of 11 bits and fourth image is of 1 bit. that is (10+10+11+1 = 32 bits=4 bytes). Now divide 16384 bytes into four parts that is 4096 bytes. each image should have size 4096 bytes. If still problem statement is not clear , you can look my code i posted below. you might be wonder why i'm doing like this, but this is what i need to do.

Comment: Well, in the code in your answer you are not decoding the image file (as I've shown here), but you directly operate on the encoded TIF buffer. That won't work.

Comment: yes, i'm not decoding the image file. lets take this example in a different way, if you have an encoded tiff buffer(byte array) only and you want to form a tiff image from the scratch, then how would you do that? I dont know if it is possible.?

Comment: Not at all without decoding. And how would you possibly create a Gray8 (i.e. 8 bits-per-pixel) image from 10 or 11 bits?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the expected images.Although i'm able to generate images which is matching almost 75% but not completely.

Comment: The problem is same as i mentioned earlier , even if i want to display the original image in that way only it is not able to display as it is.